# Algorithm X implementation for Minimum Dominating Set

Tags: java, performance, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge

As as final project for a MOOC I wanted to write a program that finds the exact cover set/minimum dominating set from the given social network data. So I did end up with writing this. I kinda followed this algorithm.(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exact-cover-problem-algorithm-x-set-1/)

I did test with the picture below it worked fine
[image]

```
"keys is a sorted list by their number of 'followers'"



    HashSet <Integer> exactCoverSet = new HashSet <>();
    HashSet <Integer> dominatingSet = new HashSet <>();
    while (keysCopy.size() > 0) {
        int col = keysCopy.removeLast();
        LinkedList <Integer> selectedRows = new LinkedList <>();
        selectedRows.addAll(G.exportGraph().get(col));

        exactCoverSet = findCoverSet(G, nv, selectedRows, keysCopy, dominatingSet);

        if (exactCoverSet != null) {    // if all columns are removed from the matrix then found
            break;
        }

    }
    return exactCoverSet;
```

above is loop to find the MDS, there are a few more classes these are the cores

```
public static HashSet <Integer> findCoverSet(Graph G, int[][] matrix,
                                             LinkedList <Integer> selectedRows,
                                             LinkedList <Integer> keys, HashSet <Integer> dominatingSet) {
    if (selectedRows.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    LinkedList <Integer> keysCopy = new LinkedList <>();
    keysCopy.addAll(keys);

    LinkedList <Integer> rowValues = new LinkedList <>();
    rowValues.addAll(G.exportGraph().get(selectedRows.getFirst()));     //add all values of the chosen row
    dominatingSet.add(selectedRows.removeFirst());                      //remove the chosen row from loop

    ArrayList <Integer> removeRows = new ArrayList <>();                //remove the rows from matrix
    for (int num : keys) {                                              //that are sharing the same columns with chosen row
        for (int val : rowValues) {
            if (G.exportGraph().get(num).contains(val)) {
                removeRows.add(num);
                keysCopy.removeFirstOccurrence(num);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int col : rowValues) {                             //remove the columns from matrix
        matrix = removeCol(matrix, col - 1);
    }

    if (keysCopy.size() == 1) {                         //if there is 1 left row check if its all elements are 1s
        int key = keysCopy.getFirst();                  //if so MDS found, otherwise return null
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[key - 1].length; j++) {
            if (matrix[key - 1][j] == 0) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    if (keysCopy.size() > 0) {                      //if remaining columns are more than 0 then select/remove
        int tempKey = keysCopy.removeFirst();       //the column with the least 1s
        selectedRows.add(tempKey);
        return findCoverSet(G, matrix, selectedRows, keysCopy, dominatingSet);
    }
    return dominatingSet;

}
```

Comment: It might be better if the entire class or set of classes was included, right now there is one function and one partial function, which is concrete enough for a review. Please see the code review guidelines at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.